# MySQL optimizator join calculation rule

Tags: mysql

I read about [MySQL optimization join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/left-join-optimization.html) and there found about MySQL decide who join will be first and i want to know exactly what is criterion about MySQL do this.

I was following MySQL example and creeate tables:

```
  create table a(
  col int default null,
  index a_index(col)
  );
  create table b(
  col int default null,
  index a_index(col)
  );
  create table c(
  col int default null,
  index a_index(col)
  );
  create table d(
  col int default null,
  index a_index(col)
  );
```

And follow her example query:

```
explain SELECT *
  FROM a JOIN b LEFT JOIN c ON (c.col=a.col)
  LEFT JOIN d ON (d.col=a.col)
  WHERE b.col=d.col;
```

but i see order who he do join is same like i do

```
explain SELECT *
  FROM b JOIN a LEFT JOIN c ON (c.col=a.col)
  LEFT JOIN d ON (d.col=a.col)
  WHERE b.col=d.col;
```

same index use , same extra field see, only order is b,a,**d,c**.

And i want to know why do d,c and don't do c,d.

Comment: what happens if you join only `c` and `d` tables, (without `a` and `b`)?

Comment: is a simple and normal join/left join , for my question the problem is WHERE , in theory say WHERE is converted to ON and here this do and then mysql decide what join to do but i can't find exactly where is optimized this query

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins are [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)

It means that the order of evaluation doesn't matter, 
`A JOIN B` gives the same result as `B JOIN A`, 
and the optimizer can swap the order of join evaluation if it thinks that this gives better performance.

---

Outer joins are not commutative.
`A LEFT JOIN B` is not the same as `B LEFT JOIN A`, their results can differ.

In this case the optimizer cannot change the order of evaluation, 
it must alwayst get a result of do A first, then can evaluate B.

Comment: I understund what you say , but me as why MySQL decide do b,a,d,c and don't do b,a,c,d he decide to do first LEFT JOIN with d and i think this do because condition WHERE force compare 1 field from d with 1 from c ?